# How do I connect to a database using Pro*C?

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-pro-c

As the title says, how do I connect to a given database in Oracle's [Pro C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793705/what-is-pro-c)?
I don't want the connection for Oracle database but for some other database.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. I've edited your question to make sure it gets some answers as there's two close votes on it. If you aren't happy with the edits, feel free to roll it back and make your own.

Comment: What sort of non-Oracle database ? Is it running on the same machine or over a network ?

Answer (score 3):

You use the `exec sql connect` statement in your C code:

```
EXEC SQL CONNECT :myUserId IDENTIFIED BY :myPassword;
```

If you want to connect to a non-Oracle database, you will probably have to use the `at` version of the command:

```
EXEC SQL CONNECT :myUserId IDENTIFIED BY :myPassword AT :myDbName;
```

and set up a database link in Oracle so that it can pass requests through to the other DBMS.

DBMS' like DB2 provide transparent gateways which can give you this facility without having to go through ODBC. It depends on which DBMS you're targeting as to how you'd go about setting this up.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation available [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14407/pc_03dbc.htm#i5880) and in more detail [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14407/pc_afemb.htm#i9409) it looks like you can embed a `CONNECT` statement directly in your code.

To quote the first article, a simplified connect statement would be:

```
EXEC SQL CONNECT { :user IDENTIFIED BY :oldpswd | :usr_psw }
   [[ AT { dbname | :host_variable }] USING :connect_string ]
      [ {ALTER AUTHORIZATION :newpswd  |  IN { SYSDBA | SYSOPER } MODE} ] ;
```

Comment: can expalin the fields in that connection statement?

Comment: Certainly. See paxdiablo's answer for a simple method of connecting using host variables. The syntax above gives you more information, so for example you can connect to a non default database by specifying `AT dbname` where dbname is the identifier given to the database by Oracle. You can connect in operational (SYSOPER) mode by adding `IN SYSOPER` on to the end and as the dba using `IN SYSDBA`. For example. For more info, do check the first document link.

Comment: Thank you. If the  {AT dbname} is not supplied, as it is in my program, where is this specified as I currently cannot see which db my program is connecting to?

Answer (score 0):

Relevant answer here if you want to connect with [oracle-pro-c](/questions/tagged/oracle-pro-c), using an [oracle-wallet](/questions/tagged/oracle-wallet).

[Connecting to a database in Pro C using Oracle Wallet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24540229/connecting-to-a-database-in-pro-c-using-oracle-wallet)

Works great to have a wallet, and provide empty strings for `:userId` and `:userPassword`.

```
EXEC SQL CONNECT :mptyStr IDENTIFIED BY :mptyStr AT :ORACLE_SID;
```