# Connecting to a database in Pro C using Oracle Wallet

Tags: c++, oracle, oracle-pro-c, oracle-wallet

I have an Oracle Wallet configured and tested.  I have an application written with Pro C which needs to connect using the wallet.  I have been unable to find documentation on this.  Looking for any information I can get on how to connect with Pro C using an Oracle Wallet.  Thanks in advance.

Scott

Answer (score 2):

I'm able to connect to my Oracle instance in PRO*C with a wallet by using empty strings for the username and password in the "exec sql connect" statement. Just make sure your SID is defined in tnsnames.ora and your WALLET_LOCATION is defined in sqlnet.ora.  Finally, make sure your ORACLE_HOME environment variable is set correctly so that your application can find tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora.