# Using PL/SQL variables in OCI results in "ORA-01008: not all variables bound" error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-call-interface, ora-01008

The following (highly contrived and simplified) example runs fine in SQLDeveloper, but results in an ORA-01008 error when run through OCI.

```
declare
  CURRENT_LINE_ID NUMBER := 120;
  TARGETVAR NUMBER;
begin
  SELECT 1 INTO TARGETVAR FROM DUAL WHERE 120 = :CURRENT_LINE_ID;
end;
```

Is there any way to restructure this so that the bind variable is satisfied in OCI?

I experimented with [substitution variables](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/sub-var2-099853.html) a little (again works in SQL Developer), but DEFINE appear to be completely invalid in OCI.

```
DEFINE MYSUBST = 120;
DECLARE
  TARGETVAR NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT 1 INTO TARGETVAR FROM DUAL WHERE 120 = &MYSUBST;
END;
```

Comment: Is this in Pro*C or what language?

Comment: Plain C++.  This is the first I've heard of Pro*C.  It looks like it about making it easier to write SQL in C than making PLSQL OCI compatible though... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793705/what-is-pro-c

Comment: in the first example, why do you need the column since you define the variable already in the declare section?

Comment: This is a contrived example, with no meaning intended beyond demonstrating that PL/SQL variables don't work over OCI.  I could generalize my question though: is it possible to run arbitrary (user specified) PL/SQL over OCI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `:CURRENT_LINE_ID NUMBER` , `OCI` looks for that bind variable in your host program only. Here `C++`. So you should have had this variable declare in your c++ program in a `exec declare section` or wherever it should be. When you run anything in `SQL developer`, when encountered a `:variable`, it blindly prompts the user to enter the value for it, so dont mix it up with the way it do and the `oci libraries` work.

In your case finally, when a `PL/SQL` is used and variable is declared there, you can always refer it without `colon`. If you want to bind it from the hostprogram, you have declare it as `host variable`. `PRO*C` supports that. not sure about c++. pro*c is nothing but a `embedded sql` in `C` provided by `oracle`.

Comment: SQL Developer does not blindly prompt for completion of :variable if you have provided a value for it in your script already.

Comment: Yes! Agreed, if we run the PL/SQL as a script (or F5), after setting the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Maheswaran's answer led me to search for `host variable`, which led me to the answer:  I was [a single colon away from success](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1063759517155).

```
DECLARE
  CURRENT_LINE_ID NUMBER := 120;
  targetVar NUMBER;
begin
  SELECT 1 INTO targetVar FROM DUAL WHERE 120 = CURRENT_LINE_ID;
end;
```

Although now it turns out that I'm going to have to wrap everything in a stored procedure to actually get the rows back.